# Security Sandbox Violation

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, sandbox

while running my flash application i get the below error

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***

Connection to rtmp://system ip/live halted - not permitted from file:///F:/Flash

work/RTS/RT/vlab/BIOTECH/NEO/passive-properties-of-a-simple-neuron/vi-characteristics-of-
solarpanel.swf

-- Untrusted local SWFs may not contact the Internet.

SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///F:/Flash work/RTS/RT/vlab/BIOTECH/NEO/passive-properties-of-a-simple-neuron/vi-characteristics-of-solarpanel.swf cannot access Internet URL rtmp://system ip/live.

```
at flash.net::NetConnection/connect()
at fl.video::NCManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::nextConnect()
at fl.video::NCManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::connectRTMP()
at fl.video::NCManager/connectToURL()
at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::_load()
at fl.video::VideoPlayer/load()
at fl.video::FLVPlayback/doContentPathConnect()
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to access a web/server file from a local file on your computer. Adobe security does not like that.

Take a look at this:
http://probertson.com/articles/2006/10/06/local-remote-resources-local-swf/

http://web.archive.org/web/20120708065543/http://blog.kazumakzak.com/2011/04/18/actionscript-project-sandbox-error-error-2044/

Comment: Thank you Mattis.I Designate the folder containing the SWF (or some higher-up folder) as “trusted” in the Flash Player settings.So now the error has gone.

Comment: Glad I could help. I suggest you add your updated question as a new question to get more viewers and more likely an answer since you already accepted this once. Copy/paste ...