# Android - Access remote URL from SWF (JW Player) embedded in assets folder

Tags: android, webview, flash, jwplayer

I am loading an HTML file from my assets folder into a WebView using loadUrl().  The HTML file references a JW Player swf embedded alongside it in the assets folder.

I want JW Player to play a remote URL.  Sadly, it will not.

If I load the SWF remotely from another server (instead of using the SWF in my assets folder) I can access external URL's.  In this case, the external URL is an RTMP stream.  For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en'>
<head><meta charset='utf-8'> 
</head>
<body style='margin:0; pading:0;background-color: #000000;'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://developer.longtailvideo.com/svn/trunk/fl5/jwplayer.min.js'></script>

    <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
        'flashplayer': 'http://developer.longtailvideo.com/svn/trunk/fl5/player.swf',
        'file': 'testvid.mp4',
        'streamer': 'rtmp://b27i9s9t3.rtmphost.com/AndroidMedia',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '800',
        'height': '450'
      });
    </script>

</body>
```

...works

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en'>
<head><meta charset='utf-8'> 
</head>
<body style='margin:0; pading:0;background-color: #000000;'>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='file:///android_asset/jwplayer.min.js'></script>

    <div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
        'flashplayer': 'file:///android_asset/player.swf',
        'file': 'testvid.mp4',
        'streamer': 'rtmp://b27i9s9t3.rtmphost.com/AndroidMedia',
        'controlbar': 'bottom',
        'width': '800',
        'height': '450'
      });
    </script>

</body>
```

...does not work.  JW Player loads - but once the play button is hit it flashes a quick "connection unavailable: error #2028" and then spins the ajax spinner forever.

I'm assuming this is a general issue with all SWF's loaded from the assets folder into a web view and is not specific to JW Player.

Any ideas?

Comment: #2028 is a security error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857418/security-sandbox-violation gives more detail.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I found myself going searching in this direction.  Looks like it is a limitation of jwplayer itself (and likely many other flash-based players).

Comment: You're welcome.  I learned something new (file:///android_asset).  I don't know if `WebView` is HTML5 but if it is you could look at using its new features for playing audio/video.